# how to use jquery.metro.js ? Unable to get it working?

Tags: jquery, html, microsoft-metro

I checked out the example given on http://naghsheh.info/Pivot/Pivot.htm and tried to get it work on a simple htm page. I have downloaded jquery.metro.js, jquery-1.6.1.min.js, and jquery.metro.css files and kept it in the same folder as html file. But the final html doesn't work as given. Below is the code I am using

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.metro.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href='jquery.metro.css' />



</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("div.metro-pivot").metroPivot();
});
</script>
<div class='metro-pivot'>
<div class='pivot-item'>
    <h3>your header text</h3> 
    your content 1

</div>

<div class='pivot-item'>
    <h3>header two</h3> 
    your content more content 2
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Is there any js-errors? Are you successlully enter `$(function ()` ?

Comment: I dont know! :( neither know how to check it! :(

Comment: `$("div.metro-pivot").metroPivot();` - replace this with alert`('Here');`. Also, in Firefox use the Tools -> Error Concole to view javascript errors on this page

Comment: well I ran it again in firefox and its running fine! I guess I am having this problem only in IE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that mine stopped working when I upgraded jQuery to 1.6.1.  I had to revert to jQuery 1.5.1.

Also, put the script tag with "$("div.metro-pivot").metroPivot();" at the end of the page, after the divs have been loaded.